# Download a text file created using HTML5 filespace api using javascript on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, text-files

I am trying to download a text file that i created using the file space api on chrome. I am unable to download it. I can only view it on the chrome browser itself.

```
location.href = fileEntry.toURL();
```

That is the line of code i currently use to download it.

Could i use content-disposition to force download a .txt file? if so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the `FileSaver` interface: http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#the-filesaver-interface.

Here's a sample that does what you want: http://oftn.org/projects/FileSaver.js/demo/

Here's an HTML5Rocks post that describes usage in more detail: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side

Comment: You nee dot inluce this js file in your html https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js then saveAs would work